# How to scrape a list of saved reddit posts to a txt file using praw in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I'm attempting a simple scraper to dump my saved Reddit posts to a txt file and struggling to get the script to do what I want it to do.

Here's some context. The script below dumps all of my saved post IDs into a text file, each one in its own line.

```
import praw
import os
import sys

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='MY_CLIENT_id',
                     client_secret='TOP_SECRET',
                     user_agent='AGENT_HERE',
                     username='USERNAME',
                     password='PASSWORD')

#open text file
sys.stdout = open('test.txt', 'w')
# get user saved item ids
for item in reddit.user.me().saved(limit=None):
    print(item.id)
# print to file
sys.stdout.close()
```

This gives me a list of post IDS that looks something like this:

```
lkj34f
ou456d
ho34oo
5j0vr4
```

I can then use the below to use each of those IDs to get the actual content I want

```
submission = reddit.submission(id="dg23y6")
print(submission.title)
print(submission.url)
```

My first question is - is there a way to open the output file, read each of the lines there and pass it as the id for the submission variable?

I'm sure there's an easier way to get this of course, I have seen several existing scripts like this dumping all content into a nicely formatted HTML file, but I'm not quite there yet, so trying to resolve this challenge using my somewhat limited skillset. I think the most obvious solution would be to use `print(actual.command.I.am.missing)` in place of `print(item.id)`, but no idea how to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers that have been submitted so far have the right idea, but make a mistake in how they use PRAW. They ignore the fact that your saved items are both comments and posts. Then, they both have a line like

```
submission = reddit.submission(id=item.id)
```

This creates a PRAW [`Submission`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html) object by using the ID of a pre-existing object, which is either a `Submission` or a `Comment` object. In the case that it's a `Submission`, the new `Submission` object is identical to the one it's created from, so it's redundant. In the case that it's a `Comment`, the behavior is incorrect because you're treating a comment ID as if it's a submission ID.

It's not clear exactly what you want to happen with comments, so I'll do it two ways. First, here's how to do it if you want to ignore saved comments (which is much like the existing answers, but with a check of type added and the redundant line removed):

```
import praw
import os
import sys

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='MY_CLIENT_id',
                     client_secret='TOP_SECRET',
                     user_agent='AGENT_HERE',
                     username='USERNAME',
                     password='PASSWORD')

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in reddit.user.me().saved(limit=None):
        if isinstance(item, praw.models.Submission):
            f.write(item.id + '\n')
            f.write(item.title + '\n')
            if item.is_self:
                f.write(item.selftext + '\n')
            else: # link post
                f.write(item.url)
```

And here's how to do it where you also save comments:

```
import praw
import os
import sys

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='MY_CLIENT_id',
                     client_secret='TOP_SECRET',
                     user_agent='AGENT_HERE',
                     username='USERNAME',
                     password='PASSWORD')

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in reddit.user.me().saved(limit=None):
        if isinstance(item, praw.models.Submission):
            f.write(item.id + '\n')
            f.write(item.title + '\n')
            if item.is_self:
                f.write(item.selftext + '\n')
            else: # link post
                f.write(item.url)
        else: # comment
            f.write(item.id + '\n')
            f.write(item.body + '\n')
```

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying the initial goal here. I admit it was mainly because I had no clue I had to differentiate between the two initially, although now it seems pretty obvious :) Either way, the second script is exactly what I wanted to do, with a small caveat - I had to comment out ```f.write(submission.url)``` as submission was not defined and it was throwing out an error. Without it it works just as I wanted it. Thank you! I'll work on the submission part, all documentation I've found shows it done similarly to the line you pointed out, not a generic submission object

Comment: My mistake. `submission.url` should be `item.url`.

Comment: I think it should be `praw.models.Submission` not `reddit.models.Submission`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reopening the file just write what you want to it when its open

```
import praw
import os
import sys

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='MY_CLIENT_id',
                 client_secret='TOP_SECRET',
                 user_agent='AGENT_HERE',
                 username='USERNAME',
                 password='PASSWORD')
out_filename = 'test.txt'

with open(out_filename, 'w') as out_file:
    for item in reddit.user.me().saved(limit=None):
        out_file.write(item.id + '\n')
        submission = reddit.submission(id=item.id)
        out_file.write(submission.title + '\n')
        out_file.write(submission.url + '\n')
        # or combine title and url on same line like this
        # out_file.write(submission.title + ': ' + submission.url + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, as mentioned in AKX's reply this gets me close, but not quite there. While running it i get the 404 HTTP Response error, which after a bit of googling suggests that the script is trying to use the ID incorrectly hence throwing the error. The id=item.id usage is exactly what I was looking for, so googling a bit more, hopefully not far now!

Comment: 404 error means what you are looking for is no longer there. You should check the id of the post that is throwing the error and see if the post still exists.

Comment: I think the issue was originally that I was looking for a submission and there was a comment there instead.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not good form to reassign `sys.stdout`. You can instead use `print(..., file=...)`.

I imagine you might be looking for something like

```
import praw
import os
import sys

reddit = praw.Reddit(...)

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in reddit.user.me().saved(limit=None):
        print(item.id)  # printed to the console
        item = reddit.submission(id=item.id)
        print(item.title, file=f)  # written to the file
        print(item.url, file=f)  # written to the file
        print('----', file=f)  # A separator, written to the file
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. This is basically what I want to achieve, and both yours and Craicerjack's responses get me close, but not quite there. When running this script I get the following error - print(submission.title, file=f)  # written to the file       
NameError: name 'submission' is not defined. It's something I hit before unfortunately and renaming item to submission doesn't seem to fix it. The usage of id=item.id is exactly what I was looking for however.

Comment: Typo fixed. I meant to reassign back to `item`, not `submission`.

Comment: Also, if you're getting 404 errors, it might be that some of your saved items have been deleted meanwhile, or they could be comments (in which case `reddit.submission()` wouldn't be correct). You can wrap a `try: ... catch: ...` around things to catch those problematic ones!

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot, I save comments as well as submissions, now I get why sometimes I get a list of two, three IDs followed by an error. Learned some more :)